# Call ImmutableArray<T> Create<T>(params T[]? items) dynamically given object with type T[]

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I am trying to call create an immutable array given an `object` variable that actually has a type of an `T[]` under the hood. How to do that using a Reflection. The problem is `ImmutableArray.Create` has many overloads and I get an ambigous method exception.

```cs
var method = typeof(ImmutableArray).GetMethod(nameof(ImmutableArray.Create)).Invoke(null, arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved the problem of finding a `ImmutableArray<T> Create<T>(params T[]? items)` method and calling it given an array.

```cs
var method = typeof(ImmutableArray)
  .GetMethods()
  .Where(m => m is { Name: nameof(ImmutableArray.Create), IsPublic: true, IsGenericMethod: true })
  .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
              m.GetParameters()[0].GetCustomAttribute<ParamArrayAttribute>() != null &&
              m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType is { IsArray: true });

var immutableArrayCreateMethodInfo = method.MakeGenericMethod(arr.GetType());

immutableArrayCreateMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { arr });
```